# R: how to optimize the position of labeling in plot

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, data-presentation

Hi I guess that I have quite a rudimentary question here. 
I have a plot like this[image]
but as you could easily notice, some of the label could not be displayed (some are overlapped with the symbols, some are just out of the figure frame)
I noticed that there are some way to adjust the position of labels

```
text(tsne_out$Y[,1], tsne_out$Y[,2], labels=samplegrouptry, pos=1)
```

for example, I could specify the the value of "pos" (from 1 to 4). I guess they are good enough in most cases .But I wonder whether there are some better ways to do that.
Any suggestion, thanks!

Following the suggestion from

vas_u Through change the axis ranges as well as "pos", I could get better plot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way around the problem would be to enlarge the axes of the plot.

Your example approximately reproduced with dummy data:

```
x <- rnorm(16, mean = 0)
y <- rnorm(16, mean = 1)

# Initial scatterplot with text labels out of plot area:

plot(x, y, pch = 16)
text(x, y, labels = paste("Name", 1:16), pos = 1) # Some labels outside plot area

# Second plot with the X and Y axes gently expanded:

plot(x, y, pch = 16, 
    xlim = 1.1*range(x), 
    ylim = 1.1*range(y)) 
text(x, y, labels = paste("Name", 1:16), pos = 1) # Labels now fit inside!
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I could play with the axis  range, also the pos value, to get a better labeling results.